# Is an “invariant” set measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I was reading some materials on ergodic theory and came up with the following question:

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a probability space and $T:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega$ be a measure preserving transformation. Suppose that $E\subset \Omega$ satisifes $T^{-1}E = E$. Then is $E$ measurable?

Thanks for your help in advance.

——

As I commented below, this will not be true if $T$ is the identity map. But is it still false for non-trivial measure preserving transformation?

Comment: Well.. if $T=id$ then any non-measurable set E also satisfies $T^{-1}E = E$. But I’m thinking of a nontrivial $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider any nonmeasurable subset $E\subset \Omega$ and let $T$ be the identity map. Then $T$ is measure-preserving, $T^{-1}E = E$, and $E$ is nonmeasurable.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Can you come up with a counterexample (or a proof) for non-trivial $T$?

Comment: What counts as nontrivial here? Choose, for example, $\Omega = S^1$ and $T$ any rational rotation with rotation number $p/q$, choose a nonmeasurable set $E_1\subset \Omega\cap [0, 1/q)$, and let $E$ consist of "clones" of $E_1$ wrapping around $\Omega$.

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer!